# Ubuntu shared folders in other drives not mounting

Tags: ubuntu, network-shares, mount, samba

I have two other Drives in my System, which I have automounting when system startup using FSTAB. And I have installed Samba on my Machine to create shared folders. Then created some shared folders in the Mounted Drives. Now I can see that shared folders in Network. But when I try to open it, It showing an error,

```
Unable to mount location

Failed to mount windows share
```

This Error message is showing when I tried to open the shared folders in Mounted Drives from other Ubuntu Systems in my Network

My smb.conf setting for that folder is

```
[Shared Docs]
path = /media/Drive 1/Shared Docs
available = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Where is this error message popping up? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The sahred folders in my Mounted Drives is not opening in other systems in the Network. I can see them in the shared folders list, but hwen trying it open an error is showing up as Unable to mount Location

Comment: Have you checked the folder permissions? Try setting chmod 777 for the folders that are giving you trouble (no problem if its a trusted internal network) to see what result that gives. Dont forget to restart the samba daemon.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 tried it, but same error showing :(

Comment: Have you tried forcing the node that fails to mount to use user "GUEST" and no password?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 How can i do that?